# An improper integral $\ln(x)/(1+x^2)$

Tags: improper-integrals

The following improper integral converges or not:
$$I=\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(x)}{1+x^2}dx.$$

My attempt is as follows:
$$I=I_1+I_2=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(x)}{1+x^2}dx+\int_1^\infty \frac{\ln(x)}{1+x^2}dx.$$
For $I_1$, changing variable with $t=1/x$, then $I_1=I_2$. This implies that $I=2I_2$. For $I_2$, note by L'Hospital rule that, for any $s>0$
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\ln(x)}{x^s}=0.$$
This implies, for $s=1/2$, $\ln(x)\leq x^{1/2}$, for $x$ suficiently large. Therefore,
$$\frac{\ln(x)}{1+x^2}\leq \frac{x^{1/2}}{1+x^2}\leq \frac{1}{x^{3/2}},$$
for $x$ large enough. But $\int_a^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{3/2}}$ with $a>0$ is convergent, therefor $I$ is also convergent.

Please check my solution.

Comment: Actually, $I_1 = - I_2$, but the rest looks fine. Coincidentally, $I_2$ is known as Catalan's constant.

Comment: @lc2r43, so you mean $I=0.$

Comment: Yes, indeed $\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(x)}{1+x^2}dx= 0$.

Comment: Make the substitution $x=1/u$. You should get that $I=-I$.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is a very interesting fact: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant